# how to stop only the hover pointer event in css

Tags: html, css, pointer-events

I have an interactive background that uses css to change opacity on hover.  On top of this (absolute positioned) is a text layer.  In order to allow for the background to react even with the text on top I have added css **pointer-event:none** to the div containing text.

This works well, but it would be better if I could still keep the ability to highlight the text.

Does anyone know away to limit which pointer-events are suppressed?

Comment: Note that `pointer-event:none` doesn't work in IE10 or less - [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events).

Comment: Yes, I am aware. This is a latest browser only concept project. The background effect doesn't need to work on older browsers.  Cheers for the heads-up though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can't do what you want. If you disable pointer-event, text can't be selected. But you can do this functional by some jquery magic.

first you put background hover effects into some class:

```
.hov{background: black !important;} //just example
```

then assign it to hover effect:

```
$('#wrap').hover(function() {
    $('#wrap').toggleClass("hov");
});
```

and translate hover event from you block into you background:

```
$('#block').hover(function(e) {
    $('#wrap').trigger(e.type);
});
```

So look into fiddle and you'll understand

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yH5ew/1)

Comment: I figured this was probably the case, but you never know what ingenious solutions might turn up when you ask it on stackoverflow :). I think you are probably right, and jquery/javascript is the only way to go. Thanks for the example.